# Resources for generating x86 assembly for gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly

I want to generate x86 assembly for a compiler course I have this semester.

My problem is that my only experience was a long time ago with 8086 assembler and I remember nothing.

I am looking for resources that have examples that will work with gcc(as) in order to test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourite documentation links:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html
- http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Please, take note of the **Related** links section at the lower-right of this very screen, as well

Answer (score 0):

there is a nice 8088/86 emulator pcemu, I have a fork of it where I removed the bios and dos calls leaving a processor emulator for learning 8088/86.  use nasm as an assembler and http://github.com/dwelch67/pcemu_samples or some other pcemu or similar simulator (where you can get good visibility into what is going on, printing each instruction in execution order for example).

If you didnt mean 8086 and meant the modern/current x86/IA processors, then pcemu wont work you need something like qemu (little to know visibility).